# can't get data from server to NuxtJS Store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

this is my code :

```js
export const state = () => ({
  products: []
});

export const getters = {
  getProducts: state => {
    return state.products;
  }
};
export const mutations = {
  SET_IP: (state, payload) => {
    state.products = payload;
  }
};

export const actions = () => ({
  async getIP({ commit }) {
    const ip = await this.$axios.$get("http://localhost:8080/products");
    commit("SET_IP", ip);
  }
});
```

the server is working nicely but i just can't get the data into the store

Comment: did you tried `ip.data`

Comment: nope, but it helped thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I highly recommend you rename your action and mutation to something like `getProducts` and `SET_PRODUCTS` instead of `ip`. Also make sure you change the variable name inside the action. While this doesn't change any functionality, it makes your code easier to read.

Second, maybe add a `console.log(ip)` right after you define the `const` in the action and see if you're getting the data you want in there. In *most cases* you're going to want to assign `ip.data` to your variable.

Lastly, make sure you're calling the action somewhere in the code.
You should do it like this:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('getIP'); // Using your current name
this.$store.dispatch('getProducts'); // Using my recommended name
```